# Installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 11 (SecureBoot disabled), installed r8168 driver from Realtek site, but still no WiFi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, ethernet

I got a new laptop yesterday with Windows 10 pre-installed, which I then upgraded to Windows 11. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 via USB (I was prompted to enter a MOK key. Upon rebooting after the Ubuntu installation, I was taken to the blue MOK screen, but the laptop froze, and I had to force-shutdown. Thereafter, I was not prompted to enter my MOK key again.)

I was able to connect to the internet via a wired connection, but not via WiFi. I have read multiple posts on similar issues with the WiFi adapter not being detected, and ended up implementing the solution in [this post](https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2016/08/11/how-to-get-your-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-working-updated-guide/). I had to disable the Windows SecureBoot via BIOS in order to do so. I get the following output after installing the [GBE Ethernet LINUX driver r8168 for kernel up to 5.6](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software) driver:

```
niran90@Niran-Legion-5:~$ lsmod | grep r8168
r8168                 540672  0
```

```
niran90@Niran-Legion-5:~$ ifconfig -a
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.168  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2c0f:f4c0:230c:70c:f135:e1ed:b192:3d38  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2c0f:f4c0:230c:70c:81f8:7e5e:3447:c391  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::9489:28e3:3526:a5ad  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:f3:ab:fc:7e:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 60923  bytes 69487638 (69.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29425  bytes 3926470 (3.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 34  base 0x9000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2208  bytes 214071 (214.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2208  bytes 214071 (214.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
niran90@Niran-Legion-5:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for niran90: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 38:f3:ab:fc:7e:79
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.049.02-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.168 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:34 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1704000-d1704fff memory:d1700000-d1703fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1600000-d16fffff
```

```
niran90@Niran-Legion-5:~$ sudo ethtool -i eno1
driver: r8168
version: 8.049.02-NAPI
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

After rebooting, I am still unable to connect to WiFi as the WiFi adapter is not found:
[image]

Any advice/help here would be much appreciated!

**EDITS:**

As requested by user 'Jeremy31', please see output below:

```
niran90@Niran-Legion-5:~$ lspci -nnk |grep -iA3 net
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    DeviceName: Realtek RTL8111E Ethernet LOM
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3900]
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
    Kernel modules: r8168
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8852]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4852]
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1638] (rev c5)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3a88]
```

Comment: Please post results for `lspci -nnk |grep -iA3 net`

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks, I have updated my post with the output I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the **Realtek PCI adapter** working with Ubuntu, follow these steps:

1. Update the software cache (repository list) and install the required dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
   ```
2. Download and install the correct drivers:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git -b v5
   cd rtw89 && make && sudo make install
   ```
3. Reboot to confirm the installation:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```
4. Load the module:

   ```
   sudo modprobe rtw89pci
   ```

Sometimes the installation is not successful. In that case, refer to this:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89#installation-instruction

If there were errors while loading the module, most probably it is due to corrupted/unsuccessful installation. Try reinstalling the drivers and rebooting.

Comment: This is the first solution that has actually worked for me. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same problem on my PC which is a dual boot system. If I start windows first and then restart (not shutdown) the system and go to ubuntu, the wifi gets detected and connected. On the other hand if I shutdown the system from windows and then start it to go to ubuntu, no wifi gets detected.
See if this trick works for you. I have not been able to resolve this issue but using this route for the time being. I have secure boot on.

Comment: Try Akshaj Singla's solution above. It worked for me :)